# Combining two lists

Tags: python, list, merge

I am trying to merge 2 lists like so

```
coordinates_X = [1, 17, 9]
coordinates_Y = [3, 5, 24]

outcome = [1, 3, 17, 5, 9, 24]
```

Comment: Close, but the OP wants them interleaved rather than appended (as in that suggested duplicate).

Comment: If the order of the outcome needs to be as it is listed above, then it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah i need to be able to interleaved!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the lists always the same length? If so, this will give you a list of tuples:

```
outcome = zip(coordinates_X, coordinates_Y)
```

You can then flatten that:

```
import itertools
outcome = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(coordinates_X, coordinates_Y)))
```

For 2.x, `itertools` also has `izip` available, which builds an iterable yielding tuples. But that's unnecessary for lists this small. On 3.x, `zip` always returns an iterable.

If they're not the same length, `zip` or `itertools.izip` will truncate the outcome to match the shorter list. `itertools.izip_longest` can extend a shorter list with a fill value specified in the call, if you need that.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate without `itertools`:

```
result = []
for i in zip(coordinates_X,coordinates_Y):
    result.extend(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If ordering isn't required, you can do:

```
coordinates_X + coordinates_Y
```

Also, you can use list comprehensions to output exactly what you

```
[ x for y in map(lambda x, y: [x, y], coordinates_X, coordinates_Y) for x in y ]
```

Probably not the best way to do it, but it was what occurred to me :).

Answer (score 1):

** the Code you can use is: **

```
  coordinates_X = [1, 17, 9]
    coordinates_Y = [3, 5, 24]

    outcome =coordinates_X+coordinates_Y
```